# Postgresql - Update a table according to a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have succesfully created a query that filters many rows from table1 and lefts only thoses that need to be updated. Now, I need to updated some values on the table1 but only thoses that are on the filtered results of my subquery. So far I have tried the following:

```
update table1 set value1=some_value, value2=some_value where exists (subquery);
```

With that, I wanted to update all rows of table1 that exist on subquery result. But instead all rows of table1 where updated. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exists` returns true or false depending on whether the subquery returns any rows.  So, if the subquery returns any rows, then every row has *true*.

The issue is that you need to connect the outer table to the subquery.  One method is a correlation clause:

```
update table1 t
    set value1 = some_value,
        value2 = some_value 
    from (subquery) s
    where s.<id> = t.<id>;
```

`<id>` is a column that uniquely identifies each row in `table1`.

It is also possible that your subquery is of the form:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 join
     . . .
     on . . .
. . .
```

If so, you can restructure the subquery and still use `exists`:

```
update table1 t
    set value1 = some_value,
        value2 = some_value 
    from (subquery) s
    where exists (select 1
                  from . . .   -- no table1
                  where <some correlation clause that connects to the outer query>
                 );
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. I tried the first example that u have posted and in where statement I added where j.id=t.id where j is the alias of my select subquery and t the alias of the table that i want to update. But I got an error that  column reference "id" is ambiguous

Comment: @A.Ktns . . . All the column references in this example are qualified with table aliases, so `id` is not ambiguous in this answer.